# How hadoop mapreduce internally works in cloud?

Tags: hadoop

I started working on hadoop mapreduce.

I am beginner to Java & hadoop and know the coding for hadoop mapreduce, but interested to learn how it internally works in cloud.
Can you please share some good link which explain how hadoop works internally?

Comment: There are already multiple answers to this question on SO.

Comment: @Venkat: Can you please post the link here or take me to the right post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How Hadoop works in not related to cloud. It works in the same way in 3 laptop ;-) Hadoop is often "link" to cloud computing because it is designed to be used with a lot of cheap machines, so it makes sense to run Hadoop in cloud.

By the way, Hadoop is NOT only map/reduce. It's a distributed file system first, and we are able to execute distributed tasks on the distributed file. And NOT ONLY map/reduce task (since version 2 I think).

It's a very large subject. So if you start, you will have to read many articles before to be a master ;-)

My advice. First look for articles about MapReduce:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/hadoop/mapreduce/ (short)
- https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html (long)

Then look for articles about Hadoop architecture (file system then YARN)

- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html
- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html

You should have a look on slideshare too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. links about Hadoop architecture are very well explained.